# Append a line in every file of a directory

Tags: c, file, io, append

I want to write a program in c that appends a line of text in every existing file in a certain directory with a .txt suffix.

Is this possible and how?

I am using windows.

The compiler I use is gcc

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You have to list the *.txt files in the directory (this is platform dependent) and then for each of the files open the file in append mode, write the line, close the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your operating system is windows,consider using the functions `_findfirst()`,`_findnext()`, and `_findclose()` to scan the directory.To open a file and append to it use `fopen_s()` with append mode,and `fprintf()`.Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <io.h>


int main(void)
{
    struct _finddata_t c_file;
    long hFile;
    char *ptr;
    FILE *file;
    //current directory
    if ((hFile = _findfirst("./*", &c_file)) == -1L) {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        while (_findnext(hFile, &c_file) == 0)
        {
            if (!(c_file.attrib & _A_SUBDIR)) {
                ptr = c_file.name + strlen(c_file.name) - 4;
                if (strstr(ptr, ".txt")) {
                    if (fopen_s(&file, c_file.name, "a")) {
                        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file %s in append mode\n", c_file.name);
                        continue;
                    }
                    fprintf(file, "This is an appended text!");
                    fclose(file);
                }
            }
        }
        _findclose(hFile);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's possible.

If you're on POSIX, you can use [`opendir()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3) and friends to scan the directory hierarchy. You can write a simple function to check if a string ends in `".txt"`, and use that to filter out the files to modify. Then just use `fopen()`, `fseek()` and `fprintf()` to do the append.

For other platforms the directory-scanning part will have to be changed.